# How to list menu without submenu in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to list my menu in the bottom of my WordPress site **without** sub menu. I have tried this but this one lists menu with sub menus:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'container_class' => 'class_name',
    'theme_location' => 'primary'
));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to add `'depth' => 1` to that array you're passing. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Answer (score -1):

The code you used...

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'class_name', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );
```

shows the dynamic Menus of a site.

From your admin panel "Appearance » Menus", just enable a new custom menu on the Primary Menu location. And add the pages/posts on to the menu as the main menu. Don't nest any sub menu. It'll solve your problem.